# Postgresql JDBC Driver SCRAM-SHA-256 is slow to respond

Tags: postgresql

Using the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.6.0 for java, I have issues with JDBC connection set-ups in the sense that client is very slow to do the SCRAM handshake:

```
14:06:55.696 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG org.postgresql.Driver - Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb
14:06:55.698 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection - PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.6.0 
14:06:55.704 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection -   setDefaultFetchSize = 0 
14:06:55.709 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection -   setPrepareThreshold = 5 
14:06:55.715 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl - Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 
14:06:55.730 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl - Receive Buffer Size is 408.300 
14:06:55.735 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl - Send Buffer Size is 146.988 
14:06:55.738 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl -  FE=> SSLRequest 
14:06:55.741 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl -  <=BE SSLRefused 
14:06:55.746 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl -  FE=> StartupPacket(user=postgres, database=tradebot3, client_encoding=UTF8, DateStyle=ISO, TimeZone=Europe/Brussels, extra_float_digits=2) 
14:06:55.752 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl -  <=BE AuthenticationSASL 
14:06:55.757 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE o.p.jre7.sasl.ScramAuthenticator -  Using SCRAM mechanism SCRAM-SHA-256 
14:06:55.769 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE o.p.jre7.sasl.ScramAuthenticator -  FE=> SASLInitialResponse( n,,n=*,r=jvD]#'Q/W{B[>&sR~djR/I/( ) 
14:06:55.774 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE o.p.jre7.sasl.ScramAuthenticator -  <=BE AuthenticationSASLContinue( r=jvD]#'Q/W{B[>&sR~djR/I/(S+vthzOvSWd/O8myC1ss28v5,s=MI7xeM3vf0Q+//Hl/16e/w==,i=4096 ) 
14:06:55.782 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE o.p.jre7.sasl.ScramAuthenticator -  <=BE AuthenticationSASLContinue(salt=MI7xeM3vf0Q+//Hl/16e/w==, iterations=4.096) 
14:07:30.176 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE o.p.jre7.sasl.ScramAuthenticator -  FE=> SASLResponse( c=biws,r=jvD]#'Q/W{B[>&sR~djR/I/(S+vthzOvSWd/O8myC1ss28v5,p=kCLAtAcv93iVblSC2EtuD2V/kHPOVCuKzY1b7+yjTUI= ) 
14:07:30.183 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE o.p.jre7.sasl.ScramAuthenticator -  <=BE AuthenticationSASLFinal( v=NjYFSEtpweE2LrBxpTaEV2mbHkPln/3Tnb5Vkcgtg1g= ) 
14:07:30.199 [default] [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] TRACE o.p.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl -  <=BE AuthenticationOk
```

It takes about 35 seconds for the client to respond on the AuthenticationSASLContinue message.

What is going on / how can this be solved?

[Mac OS X Sonoma 14.0 / Postgresql server 15.4 / Java 21 / Spring Boot 3.1.2 Spring 6.0.11]

Comment: Can you provide a self contained example, including the logging code, but not including any Spring dependencies?